# Como guardar todos os valores percorridos pelo for em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este código:

```
for(i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
    $('.chips').material_chip({
        data: [
            {tag: results.rows.item(i).descricao},
        ]
    }); 
}
```

`results.rows.item(i).descricao` me retorna alguns valores..

como faço para guardar todos esses valores percorridos no for em uma unica variável?

EX: `var exemplo = valor1, valor2...` enfim, todos os valores que ele encontrou no `for`. É possível?

Comment: Por favor não duplique suas perguntas. Se ninguém respondeu a [anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341514/112052), concentre seus esforços nela para deixá-la mais clara. Por exemplo, lá deixaram um comentário com uma sugestão, vc chegou a tentar?

Comment: Sim, não funcionou

Comment: Então o ideal seria [**editar a pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/341514/edit) explicando que vc tentou (colocando o código) e o que aconteceu (se deu algum erro, qual a mensagem, etc, ou seja, sendo específico, pois "não funcionou" é uma descrição meio vaga). Pode até ser que vc obtenha respostas aqui, mas postar a pergunta de novo não é o ideal (pois ela pode ser [fechada por ser duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)). Sugiro que faça o **[tour]** e leia a página **[ask]** e a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Colocar exemplos também ajuda: alguns valores do que tem nesse array, qual deveria ser o resultado e o que aconteceu quando vc rodou o seu código. Em outras palavras, um **[mcve]** <-- leia este link também, vai ajudar a entender melhor como melhorar suas perguntas e aumentar as chances de uma resposta precisa.

Comment: Você precisa estudar sobre arrays, o colega lhe deu uma resposta útil e você está descartando ela por desconhecimento do funcionamento de arrays e do método `push`. Procure algum material ([exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)) e estude um pouco mais.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode guardar em um array

```
let descricoes = []

for(i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
  $('.chips').material_chip({
    data: [
      {
        tag: results.rows.item(i).descricao
      },
    ]
  });

  // Aqui eu preencho o array
  descricoes.push(results.rows.item(i).descricao)
}
```

Comment: Isso me retorna a quantidade de elementos, não os valores

Comment: É só percorrer o array que você vai ter os valores, exemplo, descricoes[0], você obtem o primeiro valor, descricoes[1] o segundo e assim por diante.